# ¿Cómo pasar datos desde un iframe a las funciones del html qu lo anida en Cordova?

Tags: javascript

¿Es posible enviar variables desde un boton en un iframe
hacia las funciones del html que lo anida?

```
onclick="funcioParent(var)"->iframe->parent funcioParent(var)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible, desde el `iframe` debes usar **window.opener**, ejemplo:

```
onclick="window.opener.funcioParent(var)"
```